# Koala: Facebook fresh OAuth code invalid or expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, access-token, koala

everybody.
I'm working with a simple Facebook authentication system on my platform (with Rails and Koala) and it's almost working as expected. But there's this one critical bug that's driving me nuts.

1. Given I am NOT logged into my platform and I am NOT registered and I have NOT yet authorized my app on my Facebook profile.
2. I go signing up with a Facebook account
3. Facebook asks me to log in
4. I successfully log in
5. The Facebook application requests permission
6. I authorize the app
7. I'm redirected to the correct redirect_uri
8. Koala fails in the `client.get_access_token(params[:code])` step with a `OAuthException: Code was invalid or expired. Session is invalid. This could be because the application was uninstalled after the session was created.`

In short, Facebook is complaining about a code it has just provided. Here are the methods for authentication:

Login Action for OAuth

```
  def login
    reset_session

    session[:facebook_client] = get_client

    redirect_to session[:facebook_client].url_for_oauth_code(:callback => FacebookAPI.oauth_callback_url, :permissions => "email, user_status, publish_stream, publish_actions")
  rescue => err
  end
```

Callback action

```
  def terminate
    client = session[:facebook_client]
    if client.nil?
      redirect_to '/', notice: 'Error on FacebookAPI'
    else
      access_token = client.get_access_token(params[:code]) if params[:code] # IT FAILS HERE
      # omitting the rest
  end
```